# How to cout the std::basic_string<TCHAR>

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, stl

I am trying to cout a `basic_string<TCHAR>`. But cout is throwing error. Can I know how to do that

Comment: Can you give some example code, and also the exact error that you're getting?

Comment: When dealing with an error, state what you want to achieve, the exact code where the error is reported and the compiler/linker error. That information will help others helping you.

Answer (score 25):

As dauphic said, `std::wcout` is for wide strings and `std::cout` for narrow ones. If you want to be able to compile for either type of string (`TCHAR` is meant to make this sort of thing easier) something like this sometimes makes life easier:

```
#if defined(UNICODE) || defined(_UNICODE)
#define tcout std::wcout
#else
#define tcout std::cout
#endif
```

With this in place use tcout instead.

Comment: You could also declare tcout as a reference to the correct stream, instead of using nasty #defines. :-)

Comment: @Bo Persson: Ahh, a puritan. :-)

Answer (score 7):

`TCHAR` is a winapi define for the character type used by your application. If you have the character set as multi-byte characters, it will be `char`. If you have it set to Unicode, it will be `wchar_t`.

If it's `wchar_t`, you need to use `std::wcout`. Otherwise, just plain `std::cout` should be fine.

Generally it helps to also explain what errors you're getting, but most likely you're trying to insert an `std::basic_string<wchar_t>` into `std::cout`, and there probably isn't an `operator<<` overload for that.

Comment: `TCHAR` is a POSIX defined thing, and not exactly Windows specific.

Answer (score 3):

As @Bo Persson mentioned, another way of defining a `tcout` type would be using *references* with the *correct stream types*. Though there are a few more things to consider when doing that, as you'll easily end up with linker issues due to multiple or missing definitions.

What works for me is declaring these types as *external references* in a header and defining them *once* in a source file. This also works in a precompiled header (stdafx).

**Header**

```
namespace std
{
#ifdef UNICODE
    extern wostream& tcout;
#else
    extern ostream& tcout;
#endif // UNICODE
}
```

**Implementation**

```
namespace std
{
#ifdef UNICODE
    wostream& tcout = wcout;
#else
    ostream& tcout = cout;
#endif // UNICODE
}
```

Comment: what problems do you get with internal linkage or inline? (header only `inline constexpr std::wostream& tcout = std::wcout;` or `static constexpr` in C++14)