# Why gets address value when parsing main() arguments?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

I am using Visual C++ with the following code:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        cout << argv[i] << endl;
    }


    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The program named `MyProgram.exe`.

Then I run the program by: MyProgram.exe hello world

The program was supposed to print:

```
MyProgram.exe
hello 
world
```

but it did not, it printed 3 lines of address values:

```
005D1170
005D118C
005D1198
```

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5165240/14065

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use:

```
std::wcout<<argv[i];
```

I guess you have enabled Unicode enabled in your compilation and when you do so, `_TCHAR` is defined as `wchar_t` and hence you use the `std::wcout` version to output the wide char string.

If you do not have Unicode enabled in the build options then

```
std::cout<<argv[i];
```

would work just fine because then `_TCHAR` is defined as `char` and there is an overloaded version of `<<` operator which takes an `char` argument.

Answer (score 3):

`argv[i]` is a `_TCHAR` array, and `std::cout` doesn't have an overload `operator <<` for `_TCHAR`'s. It's just printing out pointers. A `_TCHAR` is a MSVS type for a wide character (if you're using unicode, which you most probably are).

Comment: that's the why. how to fix it?

Comment: Use `wcout` (that is the wide character specialization of the console out).

Comment: TCHAR can be either `char` or `wchar_t`

Comment: @LokiAstari yes, depending on whether UNICODE is defined. I put that in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're compiling this with `_UNICODE` defined. That makes `_TCHAR` be `wchar_t`, a wide character. `std::cout` can output narrow strings (as pointed by `char*`). To output wide strings (as pointed by `wchar_t*`) use `std::wcout`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
cout << argv[i] << endl;
```

to

```
wcout << argv[i] << endl;
```

Unicode character strings are two character wide which cannot be handled by cout. You need the wide character version of cout to print a UNICODE string.