# 2 dimensional array of TCHAR

Tags: c++, windows, char, tchar

I try to create 2 matrices: 1 of char* and 1 of THAR*. But for TCHAR* matrix instead of strings I get addresses of some kind. What's wrong?

Code:

```c++
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //char
    const char* items1[2][2] = {
        {"one", "two"},
        {"three", "four"},
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        cout << items1[i][0] << "," << items1[i][1] <<endl;
    }

    /*
    Correct output:
        one,two
        three,four
    */

    //TCHAR attempt
    const TCHAR* items2[2][2] = {
        {_T("one"), _T("two")},
        {_T("three"), _T("four")},
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        cout << items2[i][0] << "," << items2[i][1] <<endl;
    }

    /*
    Incorrect output:
        0046AB14,0046AB1C
        0046AB50,0046D8B0
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please only tag the language you are using.

Comment: Assuming you're compile with unicode enabled, use `wcout` for your second set.

Comment: `TCHAR` is an odd beast. It's a remnant of the transitional days between ASCII and Unicode. Depending on a `#define` usually set as a compiler argument, a `TCHAR` may be 8 or 16 bits wide.  In this more enlightened period you're better off going all in on ASCII or Unicode (you should prefer the latter) and not using `TCHAR` at all.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yeah, it worked. Added my own answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue we need to use `wcout` for Unicode strings. Using [How to cout the std::basic_string<TCHAR>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165160/how-to-cout-the-stdbasic-stringtchar) we can create flexible `tcout`:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#ifdef UNICODE
    wostream& tcout = wcout;
#else
    ostream& tcout = cout;
#endif // UNICODE

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    //char
    const char* items1[2][2] = {
        {"one", "two"},
        {"three", "four"},
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        tcout << items1[i][0] << "," << items1[i][1] <<endl;
    }

    /*
    Correct output:
        one,two
        three,four
    */

    //TCHAR attempt
    const TCHAR* items2[2][2] = {
        {_T("one"), _T("two")},
        {_T("three"), _T("four")},
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        tcout << items2[i][0] << "," << items2[i][1] <<endl;
    }

    /*
    Correct output:
        one,two
        three,four
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Putting `tcout` into the `std` namespace is really bad form. Might get you in trouble someday.

Comment: @MarkRansom How to do better?

Comment: Does it not work if you *don't* put it in the `std` namespace?